# Java - Scanner not asking for input, and then crashing

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get input from the Scanner class, but every time I call it, it crashes the entire program. When trying to catch the exception and print the message, nothing shows up, so I am not even sure what the root of the problem is. Some background info is that this class is being called by the main method, which also has a Scanner that was running, but is closed before this class's method is called.

```
public class UserHandler {
static Scanner userInput1 = new Scanner(System.in);

static void addInterface() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    boolean addMore = true;
    while(addMore){
        System.out.println("Please enter restaurant name: ");
        String name = userInput1.next();
        if(!FileHandler.containsName(name)){
            System.out.println("Name already exists!");
        }else{
            String[] tags = new String[5];
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter tags seperated by spaces: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
                if(userInput1.hasNext()){
                    tags[i] = userInput1.next();
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            FileHandler.addName(name,tags);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have tried several times, and was not able to reproduce this issue. I am assuming it is something to do with syntax, or something that is just not called properly. Either way I have spent quite some time trying to fix it, but to no avail.

Comment: Can we see your `main` method?

Comment: post the main class as well

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't crash, but throws an exception, which comes with a stack trace. Read it and post it.

Comment: Have you find solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you get the access to the command-line from the first call to the **Scanner(System.in)**, then you close it and when you try to access it the second time you receive **IllegalStateException**.

Try to use the same instance of the **Scanner(System.in)** in both situation.

For more info refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html